# Smooth transition to new CSS animation duration

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I have a CSS-animated background position.

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(320deg, #000, #3ff);
  background-size: 10000% !important;
  animation: AnimationName 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes AnimationName { 
  0%{background-position:top left}
  50%{background-position:bottom right}
  100%{background-position:top left}
}
```

I have a range slider set up for the user to change the speed, by setting the `animation-duration` style property.  The trouble is, the animation jerks to different parts of the animation as this property is changed.  That is, if the `animation-duration` is `0.1s` and it is changed to `5s` over the course of a second or so, the background position is seemingly randomly popped around.  You can see this for yourself in the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/x97adpe6/2/

I suspect this is happening as the browser is using some sort of time-based calculation to determine where the animation should be for the given animation duration, rather than offsetting the time based on where it is.  That is, if the animation duration is changed from a long time, to a short time, and back to a long time, the effect is as if the animation was never changed from the long time.

What I would like to happen is the natural result of changing the speed of something.  I don't need any tweening between speeds, but I do want the animation to continue on at the new speed from wherever it is at this moment.

Is this possible, short of re-implementing the whole animation in JavaScript?

Comment: Did you arrive at anything interesting here by any chance?

Comment: No, the only way I think this is possible is to do all my animation calculations in JS.  For what it's worth, there are a lot of nice SVG animation frameworks which may be an option if you need to do something beyond a single basic animation.

Comment: I was trying to keep this particular code very light weight since it's for an internet speed test so not sure I want to go that route. I think I'll just try  some cloak and dagger stuff.